# ComboBoxes won't show up

Tags: c#, combobox, invisible

Why won't the comboboxes show up on the form? (They are invisible)

```
private ComboBox[] statsValues;

public frmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    statsValues = new ComboBox[5];
    for (byte b = 0; b < statsValues.Length; b++)
    {
        statsValues[b] = new ComboBox();
        statsValues[b].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(300, 300);
        statsValues[b].DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        statsValues[b].Visible = true;
        statsValues[b].Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controls created dinamically in this way need to be added to the Form controls' collection

```
this.Controls.AddRange(statsValues);
```

As a side note, you are creating 5 combox all at the same position. When you show them on your form you won't be able to see all of them, only the last one on the top of the other fours

Comment: Thx it did the trick! Yeah I know it was just to see if they showed up haha. Gonna assign correct values now. I will select your answer as the best answer when 10 mins have passed :)

Comment: Do you know how I can set X and Y for location on one line without creating a new System.Drawing.Point? I noticed that if I comment that line they still show up on 0, 0.

Comment: Nvm. I looked in the "frmMain.Designer.cs" and when the location is changed of an combobox I created in the design mode it uses the same function to change the location of it.

Comment: You need a System.Drawing.Point because Location is a property of that type.